# How do I make a spin loader display for 2 seconds after which the main content shows up and spin loader disappears

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a spin-loader with css and deploy it on my page so that when visitor accesses the page, spin-loader displays for 2 seconds (like loading) after which the main content Appears and loader Disappears/hide. This is more like loading a page each time it is accessed.

I have been able to create the spin-loader with css

```
.loading {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
      
.loading::after {
    content: "";
    width: 37.6px;
    height: 37.6px;
    border: 8px solid #bbdbfc;
    border-top-color: #0c6cf2;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: loading 1s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes loading {
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}



.content { }
```

Here is the spin-loader deployed to the body of the code.

```
<div class="loading">
  <div align="center" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 63px; text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 550; color: #fafafd;">Loading...
  </div>
</div>
```

Then here is the content I want to display after spin-loader loads for 2 seconds

```
<div class="content">
   Lorem ipsum display spin loader for 2seconds before this main content displays
</div>
```

Thank you I appreciate!

Comment: This is bad UX. Why would you delay people from seeing content so arbitrarily? If you had a legitimate reason for using a spinner I could see why you'd want to wait for content to load, but this just seems unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) to execute a function after 2 seconds that hides the loading screen and shows the content.

```js
const loading = document.querySelector('.loading');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
setTimeout(()=>{loading.style.display="none";content.style.display="block";}, 2000)
```

```css
.loading {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
      
.loading::after {
    content: "";
    width: 37.6px;
    height: 37.6px;
    border: 8px solid #bbdbfc;
    border-top-color: #0c6cf2;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: loading 1s linear infinite;
}


@keyframes loading {
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}



.content {display:none; }
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <div align="center" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 63px; text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 550; color: #fafafd;">Loading...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
   Lorem ipsum display spin loader for 2seconds before this main content displays
</div>
```

You can create a fade out effect by playing around with `opacity` and CSS transitions:

```js
const loading = document.querySelector('.loading');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
setTimeout(() => {
  loading.style.opacity = "0";
  content.style.opacity = "1";
}, 2000)
```

```css
.loading {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items:center;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.loading::after {
  content: "";
  width: 37.6px;
  height: 37.6px;
  border: 8px solid #bbdbfc;
  border-top-color: #0c6cf2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: loading 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes loading {
  to {
    transform: rotate(1turn);
  }
}

.content {
  transition: 0.5s;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="loading">
  <div align="center" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 63px; text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: 550; color: #fafafd;">Loading...
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum display spin loader for 2seconds before this main content displays
</div>
```

Comment: the spin-loader still remained on the page, it didn't disappear.  I want it to dispear after 2 seconds and show the main content.

Comment: @ShakeelAljawadi Have you tried my snippet? It does disappear.

Comment: Although after 2 seconds the main content showed but the spin-loader didn't disappear.

Comment: @ShakeelAljawadi I changed the CSS a little in the second example. Did you notice? That might be the issue.